# Is there a way to insert something into the middle of a vector constant time

Tags: c++, vector

I want to insert element `i` into `std::vector someVector` but don't want to use `.insert()` since it is O(n) complexity since (as far as I know) it pushes back all the other elements.

Is there anyway to do so in constant time similar to the swap/resize trick for erase?

Comment: This question is not very clear. Do you mean inserting a single item in the middle and immediately having the effects visible? No, this cannot be possible. Or are you looking for some amortized cost of *N* insertions?

Comment: @5gon12eder I am looking to insert a single item somewhere in the middle in constant time yes. I'm atleast looking to do better than `O(.size())`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is theoretically impossible.

Comment: This entirely depends on who you're asking. If you ask, say, Chuck Norris, then yes, this is easily possible. If you ask anyone else, then no.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, *if* you can accept a restriction to sequential access for the insert or delete position.

The basic idea is known as a **cursor gap** (because it was used in early text editors) or more generally a **gap buffer** structure. There is a [Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer). But in short, you just maintain a sequence or “gap” of all unused items where you have the insert/delete position, and moving the insert/delete position one step corresponds to copying a real item from one side to the other side of the gap.

Indexing with contiguous range of indices is still constant time with a gap in the middle (you just have to define it properly), but in order to then use the vector's *buffer* directly as a contiguous array, the gap has to be moved to one side, which is a linear time operation.